# How to set the only possible values in an input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, css

I have an input text form where it's required to insert a value from 1 to 10.

I tried to put a mask to customize it but it makes me write values over 10, how do I set the only possible values to be from 1 to 10 and not less or more?

**The form**
input type="text"  name="level" id="level"

**The mask I used to make it accept only numbers and to make it 2 digits long**

```
function maskFormatterForLvl(val) {
$(val).mask("ZZ", {
    translation: {
        'Z': {
            pattern: /[0-9]/,
            optional: true
        }
    }
});
```

};

I tried with the "max" attribute but it didn't work, probably because I'm new to JavaScript

Comment: why don't you use input number field in html5 ?

Comment: It have to be a text type, isn't it possible?

Comment: you can hide the arrows. Check updated part in my answer

Answer (score 2):

If your input field values are numbers, then you can use input type 'number' . The min and max attributes represents number range to input. Hope this is much simpler.

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10">
```

**UPDATE**

Inorder to hide the arrows you could use the following.

```
/* Webkit browsers like Safari and Chrome */
    input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
    input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        margin: 0; 
    }
/* For Firefox */
    input[type='number'] {
       -moz-appearance:textfield;
    }
```

Comment: It must be type="text", because of the arrows shown in the number type, isn't it possible to have the same for the text type? thanks!!

Comment: if you like to use css, then you can hide those arrows.@user9869431

Comment: turns out the input type number only works with min and max when you increment with the arrows. if you type numbers, it will accept everything. You can even copy/paste text into it ( but you cannot write text ) . So, without some js validation, it won't work

Comment: Thanks!! It solved the problems with the arrows but it's still possible to write numbers higher than 10!!!

Comment: is that so ? i haven't thought about it. Good work. @MihaiT

Comment: @MihaiT what kind of validation?

Comment: @user9869431 you can see in my answer above

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex if you have to use `type="text"`

```
<input type="text" pattern="([0-9])|(10)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a text input and allow only numbers to be typed in, with the use of `charCode` . From 48 to 57 are the keyboard numbers from 0-9.

If it passes this validation then you check if it exceedes the max value of your input.

For the min value, the user cannot enter something below `0` because to do that he should be able to write `-`, which doesn't pass the first condition ( numbers only )

```js
const input = document.getElementById('level')
input.onkeypress =  function(e) {
    var ev = e || window.event;
    if (ev.charCode < 48 || ev.charCode > 57) {
      return false;
    } else if (this.value * 10 + ev.charCode - 48 > this.max) {

      return false;
      } else if (this.value * 10 + ev.charCode - 48 < this.min) {

      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="level" id="level" min="1" max="10" maxlength="2">
```

Comment: Thank you!! But what if I don't want the 0 too?